# Unable to view search results in the Activities Overview for locations I have previously disabled but now re-enabled in the settings

Tags: gnome, configuration, search, cache, activities-overview

I just went into `Settings > Search > Search Locations`, disabled the search results for my home directory and then re-enabled them with the little slider next to the item. However even after re-enabling the location I still do not see any search results for it in the Activities Overview, is this a bug or is it just that I deleted the index cache and it needs to re-index everything so I just need to wait?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18. The Nautilus search also works perfectly fine so if it is just an indexing issue then Nautilus clearly has a separate cache. If Nautilus does not have a separate class then this will probably suggest that it is a bug, but I thought I would ask here before reporting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, once you disable it in the settings it clears the cache specifically for the Activities Overview search, once you have re-enabled it you will need to wait a while for it to re-index all your files and folders etc.